# Replace the end of a string with ","

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string value

```
var strVal = "This is the best way.";
```

I am trying to replace the "." at the end of the string with a ",". Currently i have the following implementation

```
strVal.replace(/.\s*$/, ", ")
```

What if the string didn't have the "." at the end, when i try this it replaces the last character with ",".

What is the best way to solve this, where the string value could end with or without the "."?

When the string value doesn't end with "."

```
var strVal = "This is the best way";
```

It should just append "," to the end of the string, it should look like

**"This is the best way, "**

Comment: `.` is a special character in regex, you have to escape it.

Comment: *What is the best way to solve this, where the string value could end with or without the "."?* What do you mean by that. What's supposed to happen when the string *doesn't* end with a period? Give some more examples of inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your expression modified to behave as requested:

```
strVal.replace(/\.?\s*$/, ", ");
```

As it has been stated in the comments, `.` is a special character in regex and you need to escape it using `\` so it is interpreted as a dot. The `?` after it will make that character optional.

Also, in case you are looking for an expression that performs only and exactly the requested behavior, you can skip the right trim in the original expression and go only for the substitution using the following expression:

```
strVal.replace(/\.?$/, ", ");
```

Comment: What's the point of matching spaces with `\s*` that seems surplus to requirements for the string the OP has.

Comment: He put it there and I don´t need to remove it to get it working, it may be helping him with other requirements not mentioned in his post. It´s just a right trim, makes sense.

Comment: @MattBurland is right. If this is the case of just one string which it appears to be `\s*` is useless here.

Comment: @noob, I was giving him the solution in the context of his own work, I have added the expression without the rtrim so everyone is happy.

Comment: It's okay. But the solution should be given keeping in mind other possibilities because they might help others even before stumbling upon.